# Do neutrons have any attractive forces with electrons as they have with a proton?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, interactions, neutrons

the strong nuclear force is an attractive force between protons and neutrons that keep the nucleus together and weak force is responsible for radioactive decay. also, neutrino is lepton and positron is antilepton and an electron is also a lepton so, according to law of attraction, a neutron should repel an electron as a neutron attracts a proton. please back me up here am i right or wrong?

Comment: *"so, according to law of attraction, a neutron should repel an electron"* - your logic leading to this is opaque to me.

Comment: what is opaque in this qustion? i am simply asking you- keeping all the current charges aside, a proton attracts a neutron, so the neutron and proton should have opposite charges. there is a 50/50 shance that neutron should have been repelling an electron or another 50/50 chance that it is attracting the electron.

Comment: You could read about pion force between nucleons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A proton attracts an electron because they both have charge, specifically opposite charge. This is due to the [electromagnetic force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism).

A neutron has no charge, so it will not repel an electron, nor will it attract it via this force.

The reason why protons and neutrons can bind in a nucleus is due to the [strong nuclear force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force). Electrons do not participate in this force, and so such an attraction does not apply between neutrons and electrons or protons and electrons.

Apart from these forces, an electron possesses a [magnetic moment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment). And even though it is electrically neutral, the neutron also possesses a magnetic moment. These magnetic moments lead to an interaction between the two.

There is also another interaction called the [weak nuclear force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction) where a neutron decays into a proton, electron and an antineutrino. This is a decay process, and not in a sense “a force between the neutron and electron”.

Finally, taking into account that neutrons and electrons have mass/energy, one could say that there must exist a [gravitational attraction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity) between the two.

Comment: but a proton can attract a neutron? i cant seem to understand the main principle.

Comment: The strong force that exists between nucleons does not apply to electrons.

Comment: "A proton repels an electron because ", you mean attracts?

Comment: Yes I do...doh!

Comment: okay no strong force. but what about the forces of either attraction or repulsion between neutron. you sure that there is no type of any force between neutron and electron?

Comment: @sharleenelisha there will be a net *torque* due to the non-zero magnetic moments of the electron and neutron

Comment: okay thank you guys really helpful. the question ends here thank you all for looking into my worthless stupid question. i really appriciate the time. thank you.

Comment: No Sharleen. It is actually a good question. If you read my completed answer, you will see that there does exist an interaction between electrons and neutrons. I just needed to put everything in context first. Thanks for your question.

Comment: i think i found the gravitational force between the neutron and electron. i found it to be 4.1555434*10 to the power -45. but does the spinning factor affect the result? please sir tell me.

Comment: Good. I haven’t checked that result myself. What do you mean by “spinning factor”?

Comment: Also no electric dipole moment.

Comment: @Drjh what I mean by the spinning factor is that since the electron moves around the nucleus, doesn't the radius keep changing? so the gravitational pull also must be changing?

Comment: @sharleenelisha The electron is not actually "spinning" as such. It exists as a probability wave around the nucleus. You are thinking of classical mechanics and classical orbits. Quantum mechanics is what governs the states of electrons and indeed all particles in the microscopic world..

Comment: thank you for this very much needed information. I will get researching right away. i apparently am not aware of quantum mechanics. they don't tech this to you in school you know... thanks again @Drjh

Comment: That's quite alright Sharlene, and good luck with your studies.